# Writing OpenTSDB to Bigtable with HTTP POST not working (using Kubernetes(

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grafana, bigtable, opentsdb

> Updated with more information

I am trying to set up OpenTSDB on Bigtable, following this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/opentsdb-cloud-platform

Works well, all good.

Now I was trying to open the `opentsdb-write` service with a LoadBalancer (type). Seems to work well, too.

Note: using a GCP load balancer.

I am then using insomnia to send a POST to the `./api/put` endpoint - and I get a `204` as expected (also, using the `?details` shows no errors, neither does the `?sync`) (see http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html)

When querying the data (GET on `./api/query`), I don't see the data (same effect in grafana). Also, I do not see any data added in the `tsdb` table in bigtable.

My conclusion: no data is written to Bigtable, although tsd is returning 204.

Interesting fact: the **metric** is created (I can see it in Bigtable (`cbt read tsdb-uid`) and also the autocomplete in the opentsdb-ui (and grafana) pick the metric up right away. But no data.

When I use the Heapster-Example as in the tutorial, it all works.

And the interesting part (to me):

NOTE: It happened a few times, with massive delay or after stoping/restarting the kubernetes cluster, that the data appeared. Suddenly. I could not reproduce as of now.

I must be missing something really simple.

Note: I don't see any errors in the logs (stackdriver) and UI (opentsdb UI), neither bigtable, nor Kubernetes, nor anything I can think of.

Note: the configs I am using are as linked in the tutorial.

The put I am using (see the 204):

[image]

and if I add `?details`, it indicates success:

[image]

Comment: We had the somewhat same error and found that when writing a metric around 25 times it somehow magically appears. But we haven't found the issue yet.

Comment: thanks for the comment @dbanck - I just found the same, must be held back somewhere. As soon as it has some 10 datapoints, it writes them to bigtable. So far, I couldn't see (1.) that data is lost in the process and (2.) how to solve it. Will investigate some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this relates to the opentsdb flush frequency.  When a tsdb cluster is shutdown, there's an automatic flush.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think that the `tsd.storage.flush_interval` configuration manages that process.

You can reach the team that maintains the libraries via the google-cloud-bigtable-discuss group, which you can get to from the [Cloud Bigtable support page](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/support/getting-support) for more nuanced discussions.

As an FYI, we (Google) are actively updating the https://cloud.google.com/solutions/opentsdb-cloud-platform to the latest versions of OpenTSDB and AsyncBigtable which should improve performance at high volumes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I will look into this. Currently, writing more data, we are not experiencing the problem anymore. But I will have a look, out of curiousity. Also, thanks for the FYI and the big effort of you & team!

Comment: fyi, this one might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383406/opentsdb-rest-api-is-not-storing-data -- added a comment to this question/answer

Comment: @AntonLitvinenko as soon as I started writing a good lot of data, the problems disappeared. It felt unresponsive (due to some flushing frequency, maybe, as in the answer above) if I only sent a single point or so.